# Animate message using jquery form plugin

Tags: jquery, animation, validation

I am having a problem using the jquery Form Plugin. I have a form that is setup that I would like to animate the errors/success when a user submits incorrect information or gives the user a succes message when then enter correct information. However my problem is twofold. The message that displays on the same page only works in firefox with the jquery that I currently using. What would cause this?

I would like the different messages to slide into view when being displayed but right now they just pop into view. How do I make it animate or rather slide into view? The page in question is [here](http://capnhud.host22.com/sampleform2.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
target:        '#alert',
}; 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 

$.fn.clearForm = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag == 'form')
      return $(':input',this).clearForm();
    if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
      this.value = '';
    else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
      this.checked = false;
    else if (tag == 'select')
      this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};
/*this is my addition to getting the slide into view, but does not work */
$('#alert').onsubmit(function() {
    // This will be called before the form is submitted
    $('.message').show().animate("slow");
});


/*$(function() {
        $('.message').('slow').show('slow');
        $('.message').('slow').show('slow').animate({opacit:1.0}, 4000).hide('slow');
    $('input').clearForm()
}); */
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this instead, the normal show()/hide() methods can also do animation:

```
$('.message').show("slow");
```

See jQuery [`show( speed, [callback] )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show#speedcallback)

The doc says:

> Show all matched elements using a
>   graceful animation and firing an
>   optional callback after completion.

Also, you are using animate() incorrectly. For it to work, at the very least you need to pass it some CSS properties as a set of options. See the docs:

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate

EDIT: that is where I meant you use my suggestion:

```
$('#alert').onsubmit(function() {
    // This will be called before the form is submitted
    $('.message').show("slow");
});
```

Comment: is this supposed to be this:
$('.message').show("slow"){
});


how do you format code in the comments?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your problem is you utilizing the animation methods incorrectly. I would urge you to read the section on the 'animate' function in the [jquery api docs](http://api.jquery.com). Karim's suggestion is probably exactly what you want, but, if you want more elaborate animation than a slidedown-ish kind of thing, then you can either use 'fadeIn' or 'animation' methods.

For instance...

```
$('.message').animate({opacity:100},500);
```

Would effectively do the same thing as:

```
$('.message').fadeIn(500);
```

Which will fade an item in over the period of a half a second. It's not so useful to spend time using the `animate` method in this case. It would be useful in this case, for instance:

```
$('.message').animate({opacity:100,width:'100%',height:30},500);
```

This will stretch the message to 100% and show it by making it's height 30px and opacity 100% all over the course of 500 milliseconds.

In order for 'height' and 'width' animations to work, the element generally has to be a block element.

Sorry for the overkill elaboration... I'm a bit bored at the moment...

Comment: adding what karim79 suggested caused the form to go back to its default behavior.